# How can I install imagemagick Wheezy version in Squeeze

Tags: installation, debian

I have a little problem because I want to install Imagemagick in Squeeze but I need last version. Squeeze only supports up to 6.6.0.4-3 but Wheezzy supports up to 6.7.7.10 and I need this version. The problem is that the place where I want to install is a production server and I can not change the source to testing package.

I think I have to compile and install it but I do not know if I'll have any problems with the dependencies.

Can anybody help me, please?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in theory, you might be able to get wheezy packages for squeeze using [backports.debian.org][1]
in practice, it seems that there is no imagemagick backport.

however, you might have luck with trying to build the package yourself.
the following is untested (as i don't have any squeeze machine at hand), but should work (as root)

```
# echo "add backports.debian.org to your apt-sources (for debhelper >=9)"
# echo "deb http://backports.debian.org/debian-backports squeeze-backports main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
# aptitude update
# aptitude install debhelper/backports
# dget -u --build http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/i/imagemagick/imagemagick_6.7.7.10-5.dsc
```

most likely the last will fail due to missing build-dependencies: simply install those missing deps (they will be printed in the error-message you get)
once the build succeeded, you will end up with a number of `.debs` in your working directory, which form the entire set of wheezy imagemagick packages - build for squeeze!